# Bring Vertices to the foreground

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I'm having some issues with being able to trigger the Tooltip in an AdjacencyGraph, as the edges are "covering" the vertex labels.
In the example provided, there are no issues to display the tooltip when you are hovering above GLD, but I can't make the tooltip be displayed when hovering above EWK.

Here is the code

```
    graphsty = Sequence[ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> {1 -> Tooltip[Style["DBC", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" PowerShares DB Commodity Index ", " Commodities"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    2 -> Tooltip[Style["GLD", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
       FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" SPDR Gold Shares ", " Commodities"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    3 -> Tooltip[Style["CSJ", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
       FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" iShares Barclays 1-3 Year Credit (2yr) ", " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}, Alignment -> Left, 
       ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 4 -> Tooltip[Style["LQD", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" iShares iBoxx Invest Grade Bond (7-8yr) ", " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    5 -> Tooltip[Style["VCLT", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" Vanguard Long-Term Corp Bond (12+yr) ", " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 6 -> Tooltip[Style["SSO", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" +2x ProShares Leveraged Long S&P 500 ", " Derivatives - Leveraged and Volatility Products"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    7 -> Tooltip[Style["EWX", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
       FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" SPDR S&P Emerging Markets Small Cap ", " Emerging Markets Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, 
       ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 8 -> Tooltip[Style["VWO", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" Vanguard MSCI Emerging Markets ", " Emerging Markets Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    9 -> Tooltip[Style["ACWI", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" iShares MSCI All-World ACWI Index ", " International Equity"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 10 -> Tooltip[Style["EFA", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" iShares MSCI EAFE Index ", " International Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    11 -> Tooltip[Style["VEU", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" Vanguard FTSE All-World ex-US ", " International Equity"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 12 -> Tooltip[Style["BWX", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" SPDR Barcap Global Ex-U.S. Bond (6-7yr) ", " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    13 -> Tooltip[Style["ELD", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" WisdomTree Emerg Mkts Local Debt (4-5yr) ", " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 14 -> Tooltip[Style["UUP", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" PowerShares DB U.S. Dollar Index ", " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    15 -> Tooltip[Style["AMJ", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" J.P. Morgan Alerian MLP Index ", " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    16 -> Tooltip[Style["PFF", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" iShares S&P US Preferred Stock Index ", " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    17 -> Tooltip[Style["VNQ", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" Vanguard MSCI U.S. REIT ", " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 18 -> Tooltip[Style["DIA", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" SPDR Dow Jones Industrial Average ", " U.S. Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    19 -> Tooltip[Style["IWM", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" iShares Russell 2000 Index Fund ", " U.S. Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, 
       ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 20 -> Tooltip[Style["QQQ", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" PowerShares Nasdaq-100 Index ", " U.S. Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    21 -> Tooltip[Style["SPY", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" SPDR S&P 500 Index ", " U.S. Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, 
       ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 22 -> Tooltip[Style["VTI", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" Vanguard MSCI Total U.S. Stock Market ", " U.S. Equity"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 
    23 -> Tooltip[Style["IEF", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], Column[{" iShares Barclays 7-10 Yr Treasury (7-8yr) ", " U.S. Treasury Bonds/TIPS"}, 
       Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]], 24 -> Tooltip[Style["TIP", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
       BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.3]], 
      Column[{" iShares Barclays TIPS (4-8yr) ", " U.S. Treasury Bonds/TIPS"}, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]]}, VertexSize -> Large, 
  GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}, ImagePadding -> 20, VertexStyle -> {1 -> RGBColor[0.6980392156862745, 0.01568627450980392, 0.], 
    2 -> RGBColor[0.6980392156862745, 0.01568627450980392, 0.], 3 -> RGBColor[0.9372549019607843, 0.6274509803921569, 0.16862745098039217], 
    4 -> RGBColor[0.9372549019607843, 0.6274509803921569, 0.16862745098039217], 5 -> RGBColor[0.9372549019607843, 0.6274509803921569, 0.16862745098039217], 
    6 -> RGBColor[0.7254901960784313, 0.8, 0.07058823529411765], 7 -> RGBColor[0.17254901960784313, 0.3607843137254902, 0.07058823529411765], 
    8 -> RGBColor[0.17254901960784313, 0.3607843137254902, 0.07058823529411765], 9 -> RGBColor[0.22745098039215686, 0.23921568627450981, 0.45098039215686275], 
    10 -> RGBColor[0.22745098039215686, 0.23921568627450981, 0.45098039215686275], 11 -> RGBColor[0.22745098039215686, 0.23921568627450981, 0.45098039215686275], 
    12 -> RGBColor[0.5607843137254902, 0.5254901960784314, 0.5647058823529412], 13 -> RGBColor[0.5607843137254902, 0.5254901960784314, 0.5647058823529412], 
    14 -> RGBColor[0.5607843137254902, 0.5254901960784314, 0.5647058823529412], 15 -> RGBColor[0.9215686274509803, 0.49411764705882355, 0.43137254901960786], 
    16 -> RGBColor[0.9215686274509803, 0.49411764705882355, 0.43137254901960786], 17 -> RGBColor[0.9215686274509803, 0.49411764705882355, 0.43137254901960786], 
    18 -> RGBColor[0.9921568627450981, 0.8156862745098039, 0.49019607843137253], 19 -> RGBColor[0.9921568627450981, 0.8156862745098039, 0.49019607843137253], 
    20 -> RGBColor[0.9921568627450981, 0.8156862745098039, 0.49019607843137253], 21 -> RGBColor[0.9921568627450981, 0.8156862745098039, 0.49019607843137253], 
    22 -> RGBColor[0.9921568627450981, 0.8156862745098039, 0.49019607843137253], 23 -> RGBColor[0.3176470588235294, 0.49019607843137253, 0.0784313725490196], 
    24 -> RGBColor[0.3176470588235294, 0.49019607843137253, 0.0784313725490196]}];
m = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
g = AdjacencyGraph[m, graphsty]
```

Comment: This is a follow up to Samuel Chen's inspiring blog entry about finance and graphs.
http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/06/01/graph-theory-and-finance-in-mathematica/

Comment: May I suggest creating a function that gives you a styled `ToolTip`, and all you need give it are a few strings?  Or if you're lucky, someone might reveal how to set some default styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed a lot of unnecessary and even undefined matter from the example in the question. Then I still see that the EWX label is hard to reach with the mouse-over event. One thing that you could do is illustrated in the following:

```
graphsty = 
  Sequence[ImageSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> {1 -> 
      Tooltip[Framed["DBC", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" PowerShares DB Commodity Index ", " Commodities"}]], 
     2 -> Tooltip[Framed["GLD", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" SPDR Gold Shares ", " Commodities"}]], 
     3 -> Tooltip[Framed["CSJ", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares Barclays 1-3 Year Credit (2yr) ", 
         " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}]], 
     4 -> Tooltip[Framed["LQD", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares iBoxx Invest Grade Bond (7-8yr) ", 
         " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}]], 
     5 -> Tooltip[Framed["VCLT", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" Vanguard Long-Term Corp Bond (12+yr) ", 
         " Corporate/Credit Bonds"}]], 
     6 -> Tooltip[Framed["SSO", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" +2x ProShares Leveraged Long S&P 500 ", 
         " Derivatives - Leveraged and Volatility Products"}]], 
     7 -> Tooltip[Framed["EWX", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" SPDR S&P Emerging Markets Small Cap ", 
         " Emerging Markets Equity"}]], 
     8 -> Tooltip[Framed["VWO", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" Vanguard MSCI Emerging Markets ", 
         " Emerging Markets Equity"}]], 
     9 -> Tooltip[Framed["ACWI", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares MSCI All-World ACWI Index ", 
         " International Equity"}]], 
     10 -> Tooltip[Framed["EFA", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares MSCI EAFE Index ", 
         " International Equity"}]], 
     11 -> Tooltip[Framed["VEU", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" Vanguard FTSE All-World ex-US ", 
         " International Equity"}]], 
     12 -> Tooltip[Framed["BWX", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" SPDR Barcap Global Ex-U.S. Bond (6-7yr) ", 
         " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}]], 
     13 -> Tooltip[Framed["ELD", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" WisdomTree Emerg Mkts Local Debt (4-5yr) ", 
         " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}]], 
     14 -> Tooltip[Framed["UUP", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" PowerShares DB U.S. Dollar Index ", 
         " Int'l Bonds / Currencies"}]], 
     15 -> 
      Tooltip[Framed["AMJ", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" J.P. Morgan Alerian MLP Index ", 
         " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}]], 
     16 -> Tooltip[Framed["PFF", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares S&P US Preferred Stock Index ", 
         " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}]], 
     17 -> Tooltip[Framed["VNQ", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" Vanguard MSCI U.S. REIT ", 
         " Quasi-Equity: REITs, Preferreds, MLPs etc"}]], 
     18 -> Tooltip[Framed["DIA", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" SPDR Dow Jones Industrial Average ", 
         " U.S. Equity"}]], 
     19 -> Tooltip[Framed["IWM", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares Russell 2000 Index Fund ", " U.S. Equity"}]],
      20 -> Tooltip[Framed["QQQ", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" PowerShares Nasdaq-100 Index ", " U.S. Equity"}]], 
     21 -> Tooltip[Framed["SPY", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" SPDR S&P 500 Index ", " U.S. Equity"}]], 
     22 -> Tooltip[Framed["VTI", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" Vanguard MSCI Total U.S. Stock Market ", 
         " U.S. Equity"}]], 
     23 -> Tooltip[Framed["IEF", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares Barclays 7-10 Yr Treasury (7-8yr) ", 
         " U.S. Treasury Bonds/TIPS"}]], 
     24 -> Tooltip[Framed["TIP", FrameStyle -> None], 
       Column[{" iShares Barclays TIPS (4-8yr) ", 
         " U.S. Treasury Bonds/TIPS"}]]}, VertexSize -> Large];
m = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
g = AdjacencyGraph[m, graphsty]
```

Here I surrounded every label inside the `Tooltip` by a `Framed` with an invisible frame (you may even want to make that frame visible if you like). The point of the frame is simply to augment the *target area* that is associated with each label, so that the mouse can find it more easily when hovering over it.